# A problem on probability

Tags: probability

What is the probability that a license plate consisting of 6 distinct letters (A-Z) will have its letters in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ask first in how many orders six distinct letters can be arranged.  Then remember that only one of those is alphabetical.